# What is a "stochastically stationary solution" to a stochastic differential equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stability-theory

I was recently reading *Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations by Kloeden and Platen* and trying the understand the linearisation of an SDE to determine its Lyapunov exponents.

However, the text recommends linearising around a "stochastically stationary solution" of the SDE. What does this mean? I understand that the corresponding Fokker-Planck equation may posses a stationary solution, as a distribution. But since a solution of the SDE is just a trajectory, what does the stochastically stationary solution mean?

Is it simply a point at which both the drift and diffusion coefficients are both zero?

Comment: I think it means the solution is a stationary process, so the distribution is constant in time. This is much weaker than the usual sense of stationary, where the trajectory does not depend on time either.

Comment: @oLas : I think it might also mean that the limit as $t\to \infty$ is determined by a unique law. Best regards